# How can I change the view path for a View Component in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to implement view components like the below structure.

```
ViewComponents
-> Modal
---> ModalViewComponent.cs
---> Modal1ViewComponent.cs
---> Modal2ViewComponent.cs
```

My view structure

```
 Shared
 -> Components
 ---> Modal
 ------> Modal.cshtml
 ------> Modal1.cshtml
 ------> Modal2.cshtml
```

`ModalViewComponent` is my base view component from where I am invoking other view components based on the same model.

I want to place all my modal views in the `Modal` folder, with derived view components resolving to views with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook solution to this, as you likely know, would normally be to implement an [`IViewLocationExpander`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-3.1), where your `ExpandViewLocations()` parses the [`Type.Namespace` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.namespace?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_Namespace) to dynamically extend the search locations. This is pretty simple to implement.

Unfortunately, [there's a limitation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10277) (I'd say a bug) in ASP.NET Core 3.x which fails to honor these expanders for view components. The ASP.NET Core team is aware of this limitation, and was originally [hoping to squeeze a fix into ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10277#issuecomment-494078262). This feature was later deferred to ASP.NET Core 5.0, but that also didn’t materialize.

***Since then, [Microsoft has closed this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10277#issuecomment-632343938), and stated that they won’t be fixing this.***

Without that support, unfortunately, this is not something that you can (easily) change.